# Generate and store a barcode in SAP using ABAP

Tags: barcode, abap, sap-smart-forms, sapscript

Is there any way to generate a barcode in ABAP and store it as an image (.png, .gif, .jpeg etc) or as an XSTRING?

Assume that I know the codepage that the barcode has to be generated in (i.e `Code 128, Codabar, EAN13, EAN8, MSI, Postnet, etc`).

I've seen numerous posts on how to generate printer fonts for use in Sapscript/ Smartforms etc, but have been unable find anything regarding just generating a barcode for later use.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? (Other than wasting storage space :-))

Comment: @vwegert For reprinting?

Comment: @Jagger If you have the original contents - which you should have anyway - you can always regenerate the barcode on the fly, so why bother?

Comment: @vwegert that's one thing I need to check with the functional guy when he's back onsite.  I can't see any real reason why you would want that.  They want to use the barcodes in several forms (including some mailmerge forms), but from what I can see you generate the barcode straight in the mailmerge (provided you have the right font).  The only other thing I can think of is that the customer may not want to install the printer fonts required by sapscript to generate barcodes.  (I can see no problem with Adobe forms and Smartforms).

Comment: Have you seen this? http://scn.sap.com/people/robert.russell/blog/2010/10/25/barcodes-in-sap-with-the-barcode-writer-in-pure-postscript

Comment: Thanks @TimRadcliffe, that looks like some good information.  At the moment it looks like we may not need to store the BC after all, but still waiting on confirmation on what the real requirement is.